# How can i replace Object in NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, object, core-data

How i can replace object with managedObject in core data object.Please help me how i can out from this problem.

```
XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *storage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [storage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"mostRecentMessageTimestamp" ascending:NO];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor1]];
NSError *error;

NSArray *data = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
for (XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject *managedObject in data) {
    if ([managedObject.bareJid isEqual:_user.jabberId]) {
       // [moc deleteObject:managedObject];**//Here i want to replace object to managed object never delete**
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "replace never delete" in your comment? What do you want to happen to the object that you are replacing?

Comment: yes i want replace object with same index

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. You can either change an object in place or replace it with a new one. Which of these do you mean when you say "replace object with same index"?

Comment: yea replace object with same index